Нужны ли кавычки, если цитата вводится словами "как говорил/сказал"?
Как правильно?
1. Как говорил Хемингуэй, мы становимся крепче там, где ломаемся.
или
2. Как говорил Хемингуэй, "мы становимся крепче там, где ломаемся".

Правильно:
Как говорил Хемингуэй, "мы становимся крепче там, где ломаемся".
Пояснение

В данном случае дословная цитата входит в предложение в качестве структурного элемента и заключается в кавычки. Как говорил Хемингуэй — вводное предложение.

Пример: Как говорил В. Г. Белинский, «русский язык – один из богатейших языков в мире…».
Если цитата неточная или недостоверная, можно обойтись и без кавычек.

Выбор прописной или строчной буквы также определяется по авторскому тексту. В заданном предложении приведена цитата из середины предложения, поэтому пишется строчная буква. Но возможна и вариант с прописной буквой:  Как писал П. А. Вяземский в стихотворении "Первый снег", «По жизни так скользит горячность молодая, И жить торопится, и чувствовать спешит!».

Решение соответствует правилу Розенталя § 51. Прямая речь внутри слов автора
Примечание. Подлинные выражения (цитаты), 
вставленные в текст в качестве элементов 
предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие 
перед ними не ставится:
Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Г.); 
Предположение дневального, что «взводный 
нажрался и дрыхнет где-то в избе», всё больше 
собирало сторонников (Ф.); Он вспомнил пословицу 
«За двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного не 
поймаешь» и отказался от первоначального плана; 
С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в 
горящее здание.



